# method to append text in fragment causing null pointer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to change the text in the text view of a fragment on button click of another fragment in the same activity.

onCreateView is returned at the top of the class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deckbuilder_fragment, container,
            false);

    return view;
}
```

I have the TextView declared outside of any method between the onCreateView and onStart

```
TextView deckSize;
```

the same code works fine in the onStart method between onCreateView and deckSize().

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
deckSize = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.decksize);
    final SharedPreferences defaultDeck = getActivity()
            .getSharedPreferences("defaultDeck", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    deckSize.setText(String.valueOf(defaultDeck.getInt("decksize", 0)));
```

}

but then the null pointer happens here at line 180

```
public void deckSize() {
    deckSize = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.decksize);  //line 180
    final SharedPreferences defaultDeck = getActivity()
            .getSharedPreferences("defaultDeck", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    deckSize.setText(String.valueOf(defaultDeck.getInt("decksize", 0)));
}
```

This is the method coded into the fragment in which the TextView resides in. I have the TextView built in the XML layout file for this fragment. Strangely, this exact code that is inside this method is also in the onStart method of the same fragment further up in the class tree and it works fine. I declared the TextView deckSize further up in the class before the onStart method. Here is the logcat text that is relevant.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.maliciousgames.deckbuilder.DeckBuilderFragment.deckSize(DeckBuilderFragment.java:180)
at com.maliciousgames.deckbuilder.DeckBuilder.deckSize(DeckBuilder.java:35)
at com.maliciousgames.deckbuilder.BlockCardBrowserFragment$2.onClick(BlockCardBrowserFragment.java:105)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 180 is this line

```
deckSize = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.decksize);
```

I am calling on this deckSize method from a method in the parent activity

```
public void deckSize() {

    DeckBuilderFragment deckBuilderFragment = new DeckBuilderFragment();
    deckBuilderFragment.deckSize();
}
```

and I am calling on that method in the parent activity from another fragment that resides in the same parent activity like this

```
((DeckBuilder) getActivity()).deckSize();
```

I am still fairly new to Android and Java and would really appreciate any help or guidance that anyone can give.

Comment: my assumption is that the method getView() is returning null, therefore your try to call findViewById over a null value which causes a nullpointer

Comment: Where are you calling this function getView would be null until onCreateView has returned

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. onCreateView has already returned. What is really throwing me is that I don't get a null pointer on the exact same code further up in the onStart. The onStart is also running after the onCreateView has returned. I editted my question to show more code.

Comment: Hmm this is confusing. Maybe post all your code?

Comment: I just did a test where I called on the method from a button in the same fragment and it worked. I have added the code from the parent activity and the other fragment that is relevant. It looks like the issue is perhaps how I am calling on the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to get assistance through a differently worded question on SO. Emmanuel was able to point me in the right direction. I am answering this question to help anyone else that might come across it in a similar situation.

To append text to the textview in the first fragment, you simply do that through a public method inside the main(or parent) activity and then calling on it from the second fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
deckBuilderFragment.deckSize();
```

Right after

```
 DeckBuilderFragment deckBuilderFragment = new DeckBuilderFragment();
```

So `onCreateView()` has not yet been called, therefore you've never inflated your view so when you call  `deckBuilderFragment.deckSize();` `getView()` is returning `null`.

Comment: when adding that code, eclipse is telling me "inflater cannot be resolved" and "container cannot be resolved as a variable"

Comment: @user2774908 Look at my edit. You can't set the value of a TextView that hasn't been inflated. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok thanks, I am just trying to get the text view to update when I touch the button in the other fragment. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Is it possible for me to inflate the view from the other fragment after I have declared the new deckBuilderFragment object?

Comment: it threw a nullpointer on "View view =View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.deckbuilder_fragment, null);

Comment: @user2774908 I'm not exactly sure if there is a way to inflate a view that hasn't been drawn yet, but it makes sense if you think about it that it shouldn't work. Even if there is a solution it wouldn't be good practice. Why would you want to set a value to a fragment that hasn't been drawn? If the TextView isn't visible, why do you want to set a value to it?

Comment: Well the text view is visible though. Both of these fragments are side by side on the screen. Basically, the deckbuilderfragment is a navigation pane, and the other fragment is one of many that appear on the right side of the screen. I am trying to update a count on the navigation fragment when buttons are pressed on the other fragments to the right.

Comment: @user2774908 you need to actually show your fragment though. Simply creating a new fragment does not display it. This is out of the scope of your question now. I would recommend thoroughly reading: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I think you are misunderstanding my situation. It is probably my fault for not being clear. Both fragments are showing, I assure you. I can see them on my screen right now. All of the code above is from the fragment that has the text view. The fragment is loaded through the activity's XML layout file and the second fragment on the right is loaded programmatically into a container in the XML layout file. The program has been working fine until I started trying to add this counter in the left fragment counting when buttons in the right fragment are touched.